# need proper flow control logical condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic, control-flow

Below is my truth table ( OP is desired OUTPUT )

```
X   |   Y   |   Z   | OP
--------------------------
F   |   F   |   F   | F 
F   |   F   |   T   | F
F   |   T   |   F   | T
F   |   T   |   T   | T
T   |   F   |   F   | T
T   |   F   |   T   | F *
T   |   T   |   F   | T
T   |   T   |   T   | T
--------------------------
```

and here is my flow -control logic

```
IF(X === TRUE || Y === TRUE) {
    IF(Z === TRUE && Y === FALSE) {
        OP = FALSE
    } ELSE {
        OP = TRUE
    }
}
IF(X === FALSE || Y === FALSE) {
    OP = FALSE
}
```

But it fails on `*` condition. can someon suggest me a proper logical approach to solve this

Comment: The second IF must be `Else IF`.

Comment: @OmG your suggestion also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OP = Y || (X && !Z)
```

That is, the output is true whenever Y is true, or when X is true but not Z.

```js
function test(x, y, z) {
  var op = y || (x && !z)
  console.log(x, y, z, op)
}

test(false, false, false)
test(false, false, true)
test(false, true, false)
test(false, true, true)
test(true, false, false)
test(true, false, true)
test(true, true, false)
test(true, true, true)
```